# Require (allow) "xml:base"-attribute in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Given a document such as the following:

```
<patch xmlns="http://example.com/ns/lxfs"
       xml:base="http:/example.com/publ/lxfs"
       id="http://example.com/lxfs/patches/3">

   <!-- ... -->
</patch>
```

How do I write an XML Schema to require (or even allow) the presence of the `xml:base` attribute with the fixed value of "http://example.com/publ/lxfs" on `<patch>`?

This is what I'd consider the "obvious" solution but `xs:attribute[@name]` is supposed to an `NCName`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:lxfs="http://example.com/ns/lxfs"
           xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/ns/lxfs">

  <xs:element name="patch" type="lxfs:Patch" />

  <xs:complexType name="Patch">    
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:anyURI" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="xml:base" form="qualified" fixed="http://example.com/publ/lxfs" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<xs:attribute name="xml:base">` to `<xs:attribute ref="xml:base">`, and add an xs:import for the schema for the XML namespace which can be found at `http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd`. (Use a local copy rather than a reference to the one on the W3C

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify what Michael already posted, to get around this problem I first added this line to the top of my schema:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
           schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd" />
```

And then to attach this to an element, simply add the attribute:

```
<xs:attribute ref="xml:base" />
```

Wow, this saved me a lot of headaches.